# Geometrical interpretation of a solution of a system of linear equations with complex coefficients.

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the geometrical interpretation of a (unique/infinitely many/no) solution of a system of linear equations of three(or less) equations with three(or less) unknowns with complex coefficients?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to forget the complex structure, you can replace it by $6$ equations in $\mathbb{R}^6$ (one equation for the real and one for imaginary part of each equation).

However, there is more to it. Each complex equation defines a hyperplane $a+V$ of *even* real dimension ($a$ is a point and $V$ a vector space), where there is an automohphism $J: V\to V$ (multiplication by $i$) with $J\circ J=-\mathrm{id}$. Of course, the intersection of such hyperplanes has the same property: in particular, if the solution $S=b+W$ is nonempty, then it has *even* real dimension and there exists a $J: W\to W$ s.t. $J\circ J=-\mathrm{id}$.

Not sure whether this is "geometrical" enough. Apart of $J$, you also have a hermitian scalar product on $S$ and can naturally endow it with a [Kahler manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4hler_manifold) structure which yields in some sense "more" geometry than the "real" structure.